# rails facebook authentication not responding from root page of webapp hosted on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, facebook-authentication

I have used [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/360-facebook-authentication?view=asciicast) method to add facebook login to my web application.

In my routes file i have following root page -

```
root 'movies#popular'
```

It is working fine in dev environment. But in the version hosted on heroku, the facebook authentication is not responding from root page (www.mywebpage.com) though it does work when I try by directly going to movies/popular page (www.mywebpage.com/movies/popular).

On further debugging I found the message - "FB.login() called before FB.init()". Don't understand why I get this message from root page but not others when same code is executed from all the pages. I looked up for this error messages but common explanation is given multiple execution of all.js or Facebook app_id not populated, it does not seem to be my case.

Diba

Answer (score 0):

Adding "status: true" in FB.init solved the problem -

```
FB.init(appId: '<%= ENV["FACEBOOK_APP_ID"] %>', status: true, cookie: true)
```